# Use artifactory with realm cocoapods (submodules required)

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, cocoapods, artifactory

I'm using Artifactory backed Cocoapods.  I have the artifactory plugin installed and I have a cocoapods-remote spec repo properly configured in my ~/.cocoapods/repos and ~/.cocoapods/repos-art directories.

I am running into a problem when trying to install the `RealmSwift` pod.

Podfile:

```
plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources => [
    'cocoapods-remote'
]

target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

Running (pod version: 1.3.1):

```
pod install
```

Resulting cocoapods error message:

```
Installing Realm (2.10.2)
[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup

core is not a symlink. Deleting...
Downloading dependency: sync 1.10.8


ERROR: One of realm's submodules is missing!

If you're using Realm and/or RealmSwift from a git branch, please add
'submodules: true' to their entries in your Podfile.
```

I can get around this problem by substituting `pod 'RealmSwift'` with:

`pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', submodules: true, tag: 'v2.X.Y'`

Is there another work around?  This seems like there's something wrong with a symlink?  Is there a way to configure Artifactory such that this updated configuration in the Podfile is no longer required?

Comment: This workaround doesn't even work for me - it still tries to resolve the dependency via Artifactory...